# Animate image Button in circular motion

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I'm  trying to animate an image button with ObjectAnimator to move in a circular motion

```
PropertyValuesHolder tranX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, path);
PropertyValuesHolder tranY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, path);
ObjectAnimator scaleAnimation =
            ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(scaleButton, pvhX, pvhY);
scaleAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
scaleAnimation.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
```

I tried to make a path with :

```
Path path_x = new Path();
Path path_y = new Path();
for(i = 0; i < 2* Math.PY; i += 0.1)
  {
    \\save a path with cos and sin     
  }
```

but i don't know with what method to use inside the for loop
if it's even possible

I would try any other way to do create the circular motion

Comment: Do you want to image button to continue its circular motion ?

Comment: first of all i want to make a circular motion, and than that it would be continuance